# How to perform a keyword search on Elasticsearch after migrating from RDBMS tables with more than 20 association relationships?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, data-modeling

Elasticsearch Keyword Search migrated from RDBMS tables with more than 20 association relationships

Hello. I want to migrate RDBMS data to Elasticsearch and use the search engine function.

I’m not sure if I’m heading in the right direction with the implementation details, and I’m worried that I might have done something wrong from the start, so I decided to post a question.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice or opinions after reading the content.

The range (number) of RDBMS tables that are subject to search is about 20, including mapping tables (1:N relationship setting)

I want to enter a search term in the search box UX and perform a search on all fields that exist in the above table.

Is there a way to maintain the association relationship of RDBMS, migrate data to Elasticsearch, and output all related information stored in the above table when searching with keywords?

(Currently, I use Logstash to create an index for each table, add a common field that can be searched across each index, and get the key of the original table referenced by the join table.

I’m sending another request to RDBMS with this key and getting data, so I think I’m not using ES’s features properly.)

Thank you for reading this long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey and welcome to the community,

Well, the short answer for your problem is no; you can't replicate the logic of a relational database into a non-relational distributed system like elasticsearch, here is why!

The answer for your problem is [denormalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) your data, [elasticsearch wrote about it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html) before in an outdated version but still helpful, you can read about it in detail to understand more.

You can still implement the same relational logic by using [field join types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/parent-join.html) but it's not recommended at all because of performance issues, [read this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/8.8/performance.html#_read_performance) and [this too](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/tune-for-search-speed.html#_document_modeling).

## How denormalizing your data

Before jumping straight to logstash and start indexing your data, you need to first have the full relation between each table. For examle consider a One-too-Many relation of users and blogpost, each user can write many blogposts. A simple SQL database would be:

```
Table: users

id    Full name
__________________
1    John Smith
2    Adam Doe


table: blogposts
__________________
title    user_id url
aaaa     1       https://example.com/aaaa
bbbb     2       https://example.com/bbbb
```

Denormalizing meaning instead of storing two tables *(aka indexes)* in elasticsearch, you'll need to store only one (or redundant copy of your data, this will improve performance in term of seach). In other words you'll index the result of the SQL query that performs the join. In this case the result of the SQL query would be something like:

```
title    user_id url                        Full name
_______________________________________________________

aaaa     1       https://example.com/aaaa   John Smith
bbbb     2       https://example.com/bbbb   Adam Doe
```

And in elasticsearch you'll create an index call it for example  `users_blogpost` and the documents indexed would be the rows of the SQL results:

```
{
  "title":     "aaaa",
  "user_id":    1,
  "url":      "https://example.com/aaaa",
  "full_name":      "John Smith"
},
{
  "title":     "bbbb",
  "user_id":    2,
  "url":      "https://example.com/bbbb",
  "full_name":      "Adam Doe"
}
```

You can write a script (here is a list of [ES clients](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html), choose your favorite language) that does a batch process or chunk to your sql table and index the sql result to Elasticsearch. But Before performing any index you need to write your [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/mapping.html) and define the appropriate type for each field.

Hope it helps,

Marwane.